# Repeat 1d array into 2d numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a 1-d numpy array: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], I want to repeat it by having say 5 such arrays stacked along axis=1. Desired output:

```
[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]]
```

Comment: If you have numpy arrays it is better to use numpy modules not loops and pure python codes (if you don't want to use other libraries and accelerators). Using pure python, the performance will not be comparable with numpy usages on large arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using NumPy append in loop:

```
import numpy as np

output = lst = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

for i in range(5 - 1): #Put your desired number here instead of the 5
    output = np.append(output, lst)

output = output.reshape(-1, len(lst)) #Reshaping

print(output)
```

Comment: In the presence of the numpy arrays, it is recommended to avoid using loops in pure python if it can be handled by related numpy modules.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by:

```
np.array([a] * 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with np.tile:

`np.tile([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], (5, 1))`

**Output:**

```
   array([
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
   ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly that using [np.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
np.repeat([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], 5, axis=0)
```

Produces:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```